# Posts with high score (100+) in sidebar wraps

Tags: bug, status-completed, sidebar

The sidebar contains related and linked posts. If such a post has 100+ votes, the alignment is off ([any of these posts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/339?lq=1) will have a link to [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764) that replicates the problem):

[image]

This seems specific to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com) (and perhaps [Meta.TeX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com)) as [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) doesn't exhibit this:

[image]

Comment: Change the size of your current font in your browser seems exhibit/inhibit the problem...

Comment: Related: [Related questions with over 99 score display incorrectly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/229751/168244)

Comment: Are you still seeing this? I poked Jin about it some time ago, and can no longer repro locally.

Comment: @Pops: Yes, [this seem to have been fixed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jmiQB.png) (not sure when)... How about a more general solution as suggested in [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230534/168244) to the above comment?

Comment: I don't know what Anna did offhand, but she did mark that one completed. I could ask next week if you really want to know.

Comment: @Pops: Sure. It seems like my suggestion would be more consistent across the network in terms of the display/alignment.

Comment: @Werner I didn't do anything except mark the immediate report fixed, if I recall right. It sounds like you have a feature request here that got lost in an answer on a bug report. I'd post it separately and see what shakes down.

Comment: @AnnaLear: [Done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239654/168244).